# iOS app appears on iTunes Connect but not in iTunes Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've uploaded an app to iTunes Connect and it is ready for sale. It was set with no country restriction, and the price is "Free" from the very first moment.

[image: Ready for sale - iTunes Connect]

Using the search in the App Store I can find the other apps I have uploaded but not this one.
[image: Missing app]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Patience, young padawan.

Comment: It will appear soon.It will take some time to appear in search.Hope you can access your app in direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to open the "Tax..." documents and save them, despite having already accepted the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It can take several hours for your app to appear in search as it has to propagate to all of Apple's severs. Check back in 12 hours. If it's still not appearing contact Apple as it's unlikely anyone here can help.

Comment: The app was approved on November, 19.

Comment: Can you access the app via a direct link? You should be able to find this on iTunes Connect. If not try searching for the developer name on iTunes instead of the app.

Comment: No, searching for my name on iTunes gives back three apps, and the direct link jumps from the Spanish store to the US store or from the US store to the Spanish one, depending on the account I'm using.